# Flattening of wsdl inside wso2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there feature in WSO2 APIM 2.1 or higher version which could do first flattening of wsdl file and then create APIs ?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported at the moment. You can request this as a feature via wso2 github.

https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature, however I use SoapUI to import and export a wsdl effectively creating a single wsdl file (in most of the cases)

Comment: How do you export the flattened WSDL in SoapUI, is that a Pro feature?